# How I call the ShootingSettings method from the Update only when there are changes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Main")]
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;

    private List<GameObject> shooters = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<Shooting> shootingScripts = new List<Shooting>();


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        shooters.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Shooter").ToList());
        ShootingSettings();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void ShootingSettings()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < shooters.Count; i++)
        {
            shootingScripts.Add(shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>());
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().launchForce = launchForce;
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().automaticFire = automaticFire;
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().bulletDestructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().maxDrag = maxDrag;
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().bulletSpeed = bulletSpeed;
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().bulletsSlowDown = bulletsSlowDown;
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().overAllSlowdown = overAllSlowdown;
            shooters[i].GetComponent<Shooting>().slowdownAll = slowdownAll;
        }
    }
}
```

If I will call the ShootingSettings from the Update it will keep making loop all the time. Is that right depending on performance ? Or should I make some IF's and call the method only when one of the settings has changed somehow ?

I have some objects in the hierarchy with the same script attached to it :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Main")]
    public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;

    private List<Transform> firePoints = new List<Transform>();
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        GatherAllChilds(transform);

        if (anim != null)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (overAllSlowdown == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = slowdownAll;
        }

        if (firePoints.Count > 0 && anim != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < firePoints.Count; i++)
            {
                if (isAnimationStatePlaying(anim, 0, "AIMING") == true)
                {
                    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
                    {
                        if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
                        {
                            anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                            LaunchProjectile(firePoints[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == true)
                    {
                        automaticFire = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                        {
                            automaticFire = true;
                        }
                        if (automaticFire == true)
                        {
                            anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                            LaunchProjectile(firePoints[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile(Transform firePoint)
    {
        Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
            bulletPrefab,
            firePoint.position,
            firePoint.rotation);

        projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);

        if (bulletsSlowDown == true)
        {
            if (projectileInstance != null)
            {
                StartCoroutine(AddDrag(maxDrag, bulletSpeed, projectileInstance));
            }
        }

        if ((automaticFire == true || automaticFire == false) && bulletsSlowDown == false)
        {
            projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().destructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
            projectileInstance.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AddDrag(float maxDrag, float bulletSpeed, Rigidbody rb)
    {
        if (rb != null)
        {
            float current_drag = 0;

            while (current_drag < maxDrag)
            {
                current_drag += Time.deltaTime * bulletSpeed;
                rb.drag = current_drag;
                yield return null;
            }

            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.drag = 0;

            rb.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().destructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
            rb.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }

    bool isAnimationStatePlaying(Animator anim, int animLayer, string stateName)
    {
        if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void GatherAllChilds(Transform parent)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.childCount; i++)
        {
            if (parent.GetChild(i).name == "Sci-Fi_Soldier")
            {
                anim = parent.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Animator>();
            }

            if (parent.GetChild(i).tag == "Fire Point")
            {
                firePoints.Add(parent.GetChild(i));
            }
            GatherAllChilds(parent.GetChild(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Now this Shooting script effect each individual object when changing the setting also when the game is running.

I want to use now the ShootingManager script to control and effect and change settings on all over the Shooting scripts at once at the same time in real time also when the game is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always better to call something as an **event** when it should work like one, in this case it doesn`t look like it needs to be in the update.

The thing is, where is your change coming from? 
You could make `ShootingSettings();` **public** and call it whenever you are changing it. Does it solve your problem?

Also, here are some suggestions

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Main")]
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;

    //Making it public so you can drag and drop the   
    //references in the inspector
    public List<Shooting> shooters; 


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ShootingSettings();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void ShootingSettings()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < shooters.Count; i++)
        {
            shooters[i].launchForce = launchForce;
            shooters[i].automaticFire = automaticFire;
            shooters[i].bulletDestructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
            shooters[i].maxDrag = maxDrag;
            shooters[i].bulletSpeed = bulletSpeed;
            shooters[i].bulletsSlowDown = bulletsSlowDown;
            shooters[i].overAllSlowdown = overAllSlowdown;
            shooters[i].slowdownAll = slowdownAll;
        }
    }
}
```

1. In the current code shootingScripts doesn't have a use.
2. shooters can be a list of Shooting, this way you don't need to do a GetComponent every time you want to acess it's script. and you still have the gameObject reference in case you need.
3. you could turn the Shooting list public and reference it

If you still want to use FindGameObjectsWithTag you can use this, but             it can throw an error if any gameObject with Shooter tag doesnt have a Shooting script attached to it.

Edit: As @derHugo suggested is his answer, FindObjectsOfType is a better choice than finding it by tag.

Without using **System.Linq**

```
private List<Shooting> shooters;
    void Start() {
    Shooting[] shooterObjects = FindObjectsOfType<Shooting>();
    shooters = new List<Shooting>(shooterObjects.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < shooterObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        shooters[i] = shooterObjects[i];
    }

    ShootingSettings();
}
```

Using **System.Linq**

```
    private List<Shooting> shooters;

    void Start() {
    shooters = FindObjectsOfType<Shooting>().ToList();
    ShootingSettings();
    }
```

If you want it to work in the editor (for tests purpose) you can do this. This will only work in the editor. if you want to update in runtime you need to call `ShootingSettings();` when you are making changes.

```
    void Update()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        ShootingSettings();
        #endif
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that this should be like a main script controller script. I have some objects and each one have attached a small script name Shooting. In this script ShootingManager I want to be able to control all the Shooting's scripts at the same time. That's why I thought to use also the Update. The idea is that on each object with the Shooting script I'm changing the settings for the current object only and with this script the ShootingManager I want to change the settings also when the game is running and effect all the objects.

Comment: Updated my question with what I mean.

Comment: I'ld say thks answer is half way there. What really is expensive is `Find` and `GetComponent` in `Update` allways try to avoid that! If you can get them all in `Start` store them.and later reuse the references.

Comment: @yochile, this script does what you want, it changes all the variables you want from the Shooting's script and make them equal to the ShootingManager class.  Can you tell us where the change is being made? In the inspector? another script?

Comment: There is actually no reason for converting the result of `FindObjectsOfType` to a List though ;)

Comment: @derHugo There is, he was using a list at the start and FindObjectsOfType returns an array. It won't compile if he doesn't convert.

Comment: Exactlyy point is there is no reason to use a list at all. Should rather stick with an `Shooting[]` :)

Comment: @FelipeDrude The changes should be make in the editor mode in the inspector but also when the game is running already. The idea is to make it effecting the Shooting scripts while the game is running. Your answer will effect it only when making changes before running the game and then running the game. I want that if I change any settings in the ShootingManager script while the game is running then make this changes also to the shooting scripts.

Comment: @yochile     ShootingSettings(); updates the info in all the Shooting scripts. It can solve your problem while the game is running, you only need to call it when you are going to change something. `bulletSpeed = X; and then ShootingSettings(); ` but for it to work in the inspector you could put it in the check for unity editor (I will add it in the code for you). But let me be clear, you are the that need to know what design is the best for you, you could turn this variables static, make a scriptableObject (Like @derHugo suggested) or update it when you need.

Comment: I personally suggest you check ScriptableObjects, it`s a good thing to learn.
Here are some videos that could help you. 


Brackeys:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY 

Unite Austin 2017 - Game Architecture with Scriptable Objects:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk

Answer (score 1):

What the other answer does not cover is syncing those changes when you make them live in the UnityEditor (Inspector) e.g. for fine tuning them.

It sounds like the perfect use case for [ScriptableObject](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects)

```
[CreateAssetMenu (fileName = "new ShootingSettings", menuName = "ShootingSettings")]
public class ShootingSettings : ScriptableObject
{      
    [Header("Main")]
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;
}
```

Create an instance by right click in the Assets -> Create -> ShootingSettings and give it a name.

Now change your `Shooting` class and the manager class instead have a

```
public ShootingSettings settings;
```

So from the manager use [`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) which btw is way more efficient than using `FindObjectsWithTag` and multiple times `GetComponent`!

```
private void Awake()
{
    // This is way more efficient than using find and GetComponent over and over again
    foreach(var shooting in FindObjectsOfType<Shooting>())
    {
        shooting.settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Now reference the asset you created before to the `settings` field of the manager script.

From now on any change you make to that created asset will be applied to all `settings` of all `Shootig` instances. So all that's left to do is change your `Shooting` script to use those settings instead ;)

---

Alternatively you could do the same thing actually also without `ScriptableObject` by simply having the class

```
[Serializable]
public class ShootingSettings
{      
    [Header("Main")]
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;
}
```

instead. In this case you can make all settings directly in the manager class. Since all `Shooting` instances will then use the same instance reference every later change to the `settings` in the manager are done on the same `settings` Instance all your components share.

---

=> You wouldn't need any method nor event for getting the settings updated everywhere :)

---

*Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*